# Dplyr mutate minimum column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df with many columns but for this issue am focusing on four date columns `A, B, C, D`. I am using the following to create a column for the minimum date for that row.

```
mutate(MIN_DATE = pmin(A,B,C,D))
```

To create a column for the minimum date for that row.

```
  A         B       C       D       MIN_DATE
1-1-20   1-2-20  1-10-20  2-10-20    1-1-20
1-2-20   1-4-20  1-11-20  2-1-20     1-2-20
1-3-20   1-5-20  1-20-20  2-3-20     1-3-20
```

What I would like to do is add another column which is the column name of the minimum date which would look like :

```
  A         B       C       D       MIN_DATE   MIN_COL
1-1-20   1-2-20  1-10-20  2-10-20    1-1-20       A
1-2-20   1-4-20  1-11-20  2-1-20     1-2-20       A
1-3-20   1-5-20  1-2-20   2-3-20     1-3-20       C
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this, some combination of `names` and `which.min()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `which.min` to get the index of minimum date and use that to subset the `names` after doing `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
   # in case the dates are not Date class
   mutate(across(c(A, B, C, D), mdy)) %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(MIN_COL = names(.)[1:4][which.min(c_across(c(A, B, C, D)))]) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  A          B          C          D          MIN_COL
  <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <chr>  
1 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-10 2020-02-10 A      
2 2020-01-02 2020-01-04 2020-01-11 2020-02-01 A      
3 2020-01-03 2020-01-05 2020-01-20 2020-02-03 A
```

---

Or probably a faster option with `max.col` from `base R`

```
df$MIN_COL <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")[max.col(-sapply(
    df[c("A", "B", "C", "D")], \(x) as.Date(x, "%m-%d-%y")), "first")]
```

Comment: Ty! How would I edit this if A,B,C,D are not next to each other in the dataframe? is it possible to just do c_across(A,B,C,D)?

Comment: @user3249770 you can `c` to concatenate  as a vectori.e. `c(A, B, C, D)`

Comment: @user3249770 similarly the `names(.)[1:4]` should be changed with appropriate index i.d. `names(.)[c(1, 2, 3, 4)]` or the column positions in your original data

Comment: Getting :x Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `date`.
ℹ It must be numeric or character.

Comment: @user3249770 As I mentioned in the code, I am converting the character to `Date` class in `mutate(across(A:D, mdy))`  Probaby you need `mutate(across(c(A, B, C, D), mdy))` if columns are not in range

Comment: Love the `max.col` answer :)